# Can someone review my excel error and provide feedback on the code?

Tags: excel

We have a large excel spreadsheet that has been in use for a view years now, the original coder for it has moved on. Today we started to get an a runtime error "Compile error, Syntax error"  highlighting the below code

```
For n = 7 To lastpivotrow
    If Range("AA" & n).Value <> "" And lastpivotrow < 50 Then
        Range("B" & nextentry).Value = Range("AB" & n).Value
        Range("C" & nextentry).Value = Range("AC" & n).Value
        Range("D" & nextentry).Value = Range("AD" & n).Value
        Range("E" & nextentry).Value = Range("AE" & n).Value
        Range("B" & nextentry, "E" & nextentry).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous
        Range("B" & nextentry, "E" & nextentry).Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Range("B" & nextentry, "E" & nextentry).Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Range("B" & nextentr+hen Range("B" & nextentry, "E" & nextentry).Interior.ColorIndex = 39
        nextentry = nextentry + 1
```

Can anyone see whats wrong with this and provide feedback?

Comment: The lines `End If` and `Next n` would be essential. When the code breaks the item being objected to may be highlighted. If not, how do you know that the error is within the lines you show us?

Comment: look at this line `Range("B" & nextentr+hen Range`. I suspect someone leaned on the keyboard there. it might be `Range("B" & nextentry, Range`. Perhaps `+hen Range("B" & nextentry` was inserted.